# Angular - search data based on selected item

Tags: angular, typescript, api

I am trying to search data depending upon selected item, as of now global search is working for all items.
suppose if i select mobile item and then type iphone 11 in search then search should be done only on mobile array list.
Can anyone please help and tell me How to search data on basis of selected option (category).

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="mt-4">
    <div class="form-group has-search">
      <span class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback"></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="searchKeywords" (keyup)="getSmartSearchValues(searchKeywords)" placeholder="Search here">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs mt-3" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#list" (click)="getAllData()">All</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#list" (click)="getGlobalSearchList('DancingGoatMvc-Coffee')">Coffee</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#list" (click)="getGlobalSearchList('DancingGoatMvc-Brewer')">Brewer</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#list" (click)="getGlobalSearchList('DancingGoatMvc-Mobile')">Mobile</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#list" (click)="getGlobalSearchList('DancingGoatMvc-Laptop')">Laptop</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="col p-0">
      <h5 class="mt-2">Total Results - {{this.CoffeeItemList.length}} Products</h5>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane container active in">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="card col-3" *ngFor="let items of CoffeeItemList">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{items?.title }}</h5>
          <div class="img-box">

            <img src="http://infogainpune.com{{items.image |slice:1}}" class="w-100" onerror="this.src='https://thestonecafe.com/saved/noImageAvailable.gif';"  alt="..." />
          </div>
          <p class="card-text">{{items?.content}}</p>
          <h4 class="card-text item-prics">${{items?.price}}</h4>
          <h5 class="card-text item-type"> {{items?.type | slice:15}}</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="! CoffeeItemList?.length" class="mt-5 text-center">
       <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRMp-5DU0H4U_joMB6heA3nMMcUZe8EjqMqb0nVRql4CbTWSi6V"/>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS

```
searchKeywords: string;
  coffeeResults: any;
  CoffeeItemList: any = [];

  // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
  constructor(private getDataListingService: DataListingService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getGlobalSearchList('');
    this.getAllData();
  }
  getAllData() {
    this.getDataListingService.getAllDataLists().subscribe(value => {
      this.CoffeeItemList = value.data;
    });
  }
  getGlobalSearchList(type: string) {
    this.CoffeeItemList = [];
    this.getDataListingService.getAllDataLists().subscribe(value => {
      let data = [];
      data = value.data;
      console.log(data);
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
        if (data[i].type === type) {
            this.CoffeeItemList.push(data[i]);
        }
    }
    });
  }
  getSmartSearchValues(search: string) {
    if (search === '' ) {
      this.getGlobalSearchList('');
      return false;
    }
    this.getDataListingService.searchList(search).subscribe(value => {
      this.CoffeeItemList = value.data;
    });

  }
}
```

This service code is for searching data 
smart-search.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SmartSearchList } from '../shared/models/smartSearchList';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SmartSearchService {

  baseUrl = 'apiurlhere';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllSmartSearchDataLists(): Observable<SmartSearchList> {
    return this.http.get<SmartSearchList>(this.baseUrl);
  }
}
```

Displaying list of product
data-listing.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DataLists  } from '../shared/models/dataListing';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataListingService {
  baseUrl = 'http://infogainpune.com/api/products';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllDataLists(): Observable<DataLists> {
    return this.http.get<DataLists>(this.baseUrl);
  }

  searchList(search: string): Observable<DataLists> {
    return this.http.get<DataLists>('search url here' + search);
  }
}
```

JSON Response

[image]

JSON Product response attributes
[image]

Comment: You are currently doing a service call for searching. Can you share the service code?

Comment: Please post json data of `CoffeeItemList`.

Comment: @RounakSnehasis - i have added service code. please have a look.

Comment: @hrdkisback- added JSON response too

Comment: How you are map each item with category like `iphone 11` with `mobile` in json data?  Is there any property in data like `category`?

Comment: @hrdkisback - Yes in json data i get type attribute on basis of that i m filtering category wise data, i have attached image in question (named as -JSON Product response attributes )

Comment: In `getSmartSearchValues()` method you need to filter second time based on selected type.

Comment: @hrdkisback- yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,
Take one variable to store selected type value.

**TS**

```
selectedType: string = '';

getGlobalSearchList(type: string) {

    this.selectedType = type;
    this.CoffeeItemList = [];
    this.getDataListingService.getAllDataLists().subscribe(value => {

        let data = [];
        data = value.data;
        console.log(data);
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
            if (data[i].type === type) {
                this.CoffeeItemList.push(data[i]);
            }
        }
    });
}

getSmartSearchValues(search: string) {
    if (search === '' ) {
        this.getGlobalSearchList('');
        return false;
    }
    this.getDataListingService.searchList(search).subscribe(value => {

        let data = [];
        data = value.data;
        this.CoffeeItemList = value.data;

        // check selected type either coffee, mobile or ALL.
        if(this.selectedType && this.selectedType != '') {
            this.CoffeeItemList = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
                if (data[i].type === this.selectedType) {
                    this.CoffeeItemList.push(data[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @hrdkisback- sorry it is not working for specific category

Comment: Hey it is working now i have just removed length-1 from for loop

Comment: Oke glad to hear that, You can refactor the duplicate code in both methods.