# Angular - How can i optimize my code for improving load time ? Current load time is 2.45sec

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, loops

I'm trying to optimize the speed (happens to make my code faster). How can I optimize below piece of code so that load time get optimize further. And if possible, please suggest what I should usually keep in mind.
As of now Finish time = 2.45sec.

TS

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  searchKeywords: string;
  CoffeeItemList: any = [];
  type: string;
  search: string;
  selectedType = '';
  showLoader: boolean;
  empty = false;
  data: any = [];

  // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
  constructor(private getDataListingService: DataListingService) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getGlobalSearchList('');
    this.getAllData();
    this.getSmartSearchValues('');
    if (this.CoffeeItemList.length === 0) {
      this.empty = true;
      }
  }
  getAllData() {
    this.showLoader = true;
    this.getDataListingService.getAllDataLists().subscribe(value => {
      this.CoffeeItemList = value.data;
      this.showLoader = false;
    });
  }
  getGlobalSearchList(type: string) {
    this.selectedType = type;
    this.CoffeeItemList = [];
    this.getDataListingService.getAllDataLists().subscribe(value => {
        this.data = value.data;
        console.log(this.data);
        // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-for-of
        for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
            if (this.data[i].type === type) {
                this.CoffeeItemList.push(this.data[i]);
            }
        }
    });
}
getSmartSearchValues(search: string) {
  if (search === '' ) {
      this.getAllData();
      return false;
  }
  if (search.length >= 3) {
    this.getDataListingService.searchList(search).subscribe(value => {
        this.data = value.data;
        this.CoffeeItemList = value.data;
        // check selected type either coffee, mobile or ALL.
        if (this.selectedType && this.selectedType !== '' ) {
            this.CoffeeItemList = [];
            // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-for-of
            for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
                if (this.data[i].type === this.selectedType) {
                    this.CoffeeItemList.push(this.data[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    });
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Your API calls will be adding a lot of delay here. If you want to focus on improving the efficiency of your Angular then benchmark against controlled mocks rather than variable requests.

Comment: Your `getSmartSearchValues(search: string)` will be called on every key up, instead of you can do like when user stop typing it will search and filter data, So it will avoid extra API calls of `searchList`. Refer this http://blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2016/10/trigger-event-when-user-finishes-typing.html#.XlT5YHUzY5k

Comment: Also, you are currently checking `this.CoffeeItemList.length` in `ngOnInit` outside the observables, so it is likely to be undefined when you check it.

Comment: @hrdkisback How do we know that's called on every keyup?

Comment: @KurtHamilton https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60262481/angular-search-data-based-on-selected-item/60275519#60275519  ;)

Comment: @hrdkisback Ha, good spot. Still, not officially within scope of the question, but it probably should be.

Comment: Seems this user is making alot of rookie mistakes. Just try to stick with the question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you call `getAllDataLists` twice why?
Can't one of these subscribe be made redundant?

Second try to filter out more data cause atleast 1 second for a call is alot of data `getAllDataLists` should be filter before you load all the data into your application.
Either it's to much data so you should check your network tab. Or the html is to complicated and load way to much data and that's why your aplication is getting so slow.

Also I see you're making the same mistakes with subscription?
You know it will trigger everytime data get changed? So with your current setup and if you subscribe on every keyup you will create 100 of subsciptions that never finish and keep poling for changes.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60389896/7672014

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you call your service *getDataListingService* three times in ngOnInit() and every time you make a request and, I suppose, you collect data and then you work on data.

I'd like to see your HTML file as well. Maybe you don't need to make that much requests on init.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you have shared:

1. You need to add some sort of pagination to your 'getAllDataLists' & 'searchList' methods i.e. you always get results in chunks instead of getting larger data results to render on the UI.
2. The following methods when called are performing API calls that can all be combined into 1 single API call to reduce the memory load and reduce wait time for user to see results/data being rendered on the page.

   ```
   this.getGlobalSearchList('');
   this.getAllData();
   this.getSmartSearchValues('');
   ```
3. Optimize your API call e.g. send the 'selectedType' in the API itself to already get filtered results from the backend instead of adding a check of `if (this.selectedType && this.selectedType !== '' )`